# Suppressing link with empty target \thref

Tags: latex

I am writing a document in LaTEX and getting a warning that I seem not to bee able to get rid of:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[amsmath,thref]{ntheorem}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
% Usefull Shortcuts and other refs
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\begin{document}
    \begin{remark}[Notation: Mode Orderig and Tensor Contraction]\label{rem:MOTC}
        Consider two tensors $A_{ack},B_{dkb}$ then the expressions
        \begin{equation*}
            C_{abcd} = A_{ack}B_{dkb}
        \end{equation*}
        and
        \begin{equation*}
            C_{abcd} = ((A_{ack}(B_{dkb})^{T_{1,2}})^{T_{2,4}})^{T_{3,4}}
        \end{equation*}
        are equivalent.    
    \end{remark}
    The apparent inconsistence can be solved by impling the application of the Transposition Operation,like in \thref{rem:MOTC}.
\end{document}
```

The last line throws the warning `Suppressing link with empty target`.
I have sofar tried to change the numbering pattern of remarks but without any progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- you are missing the `hyperref` option if you want to use `ntheorem` with hyperref
- change the loading order of your packages and move `ntheorem` before `bookmark`/`hyperref`

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[amsmath,thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}

% Usefull Shortcuts and other refs
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{remark}[Notation: Mode Orderig and Tensor Contraction]\label{rem:MOTC}
        Consider two tensors $A_{ack},B_{dkb}$ then the expressions
        \begin{equation*}
            C_{abcd} = A_{ack}B_{dkb}
        \end{equation*}
        and
        \begin{equation*}
            C_{abcd} = ((A_{ack}(B_{dkb})^{T_{1,2}})^{T_{2,4}})^{T_{3,4}}
        \end{equation*}
        are equivalent.    
    \end{remark}
    The apparent inconsistence can be solved by impling the application of the Transposition Operation, like in \thref{rem:MOTC}.
\end{document}
```

[image]